# Running code only every n seconds (controlling the frequency of AJAX requests)

Tags: jquery

I have some code that is executed on the `keyup` event:

```
$('#some-text-box').keyup(function() {
   var $text = $(this).text();
   // do some ajax stuff using $text
});
```

How do I change the above to only do an AJAX request every `n` milliseconds?

Thank you :).

Comment: You mean to limit it so that it doesn't do more than one request ever `n` milliseconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var flag = true;
$('#some-text-box').keyup(function() {
   var $text = $(this).text();
   if(flag){          
      flag = false;
      $.ajax({
         // other parameter
         success : function(){                  
             setTimeout(function(){
                 flag = true;
                }, 5000);
         }
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: I dont think you should wait for the ajax success result to set the flag, this could take too long and allow the user to `keyup` many more times (and thus fire many more ajax requests) before the flag gets set

Comment: pls check the code again.. i think it will fullfill the OP requirement.

Comment: You could probably skip the `clearTimeout` since it will never run as long as the current `setTimeout` is still pending.

Answer (score 3):

this should work for you...

```
var canAjaxFlag = true;

$('#some-text-box').keyup(function() {
   var $text = $(this).text();
   if(canAjaxFlag){
      canAjaxFlag = false;//set this as quickly as possible
      // do some ajax stuff using $text
      setTimeout(function(){
         canAjaxFlag = true;
      }, 1000);
   }
});
```

You will see that the interval has been set to `1000` milliseconds, you can change this to suit your needs

**IMPORTANT**: Use `setTimeout` not `setInterval`, you don't want it to keep running after the falg is set back to `true` - thanks to @amnotiam for the heads up

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/x4Hwn/)

Comment: This is a little bit better than some of the others, but why are you using `setInterval`? You're going to end up having multiple intervals running, all setting the `canAjaxFlag` to `true`.

Comment: @amnotiam: How multiple? they next interval can only be kicked off once the first has completed... or maybe I meant to use `setTimeout`... fixed

Answer (score 0):

Inside your document ready function -

```
var params = null;
var frequency = 300;

$('#some-text-box').keyup(function() {
   var $text = $(this).text();
   params = {
     //stuff we'd like to send to the server
   }
});

setInterval(function() {
  if (params !== null) {
     $.ajax({
         //Send in params here
     });
     params = null;
  }
}, frequency);
```